# cannot find RooEntity annotation in spring Roo > 1.1.5

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-roo

We are using spring roo 1.1.5 and we want to upgrade version of spring roo.

We have some classes annotated with RooEntity. For example,

```
import org.springframework.roo.addon.entity.RooEntity;
@RooEntity
public class X {
...
}
```

But, I cannot find this class anywhere in later version of spring roo. My maven dependancy is as follows:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.roo</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.roo.annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${roo.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

How do I upgrade spring roo to current version 1.3.1.RELEASE given that we use RooEntity annotation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RooEntity was replaced by RooJpaActiveRecord. Have a look at http://www.kevinhooke.com/2013/02/06/spring-roo-rooentity-from-1-1-x-replaced-in-1-2-x/